# What does implementation-defined value in FileAPI/unicodeBlobURL mean?

Tags: url, browser, w3c, fileapi

In https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#unicodeBlobURL:

The Serialization of a Blob URL is the value returned by the following algorithm, which is invoked by URL.createObjectURL():

1. Let result be the empty string. Append the string "blob" (that is, the Unicode code point sequence U+0062, U+006C, U+006F, U+0062) to result.
2. Append the ":" (U+003A COLON) character to result.
3. Let settings be the current settings object
4. Let origin be settings’s origin.
5. Let serialized be the ASCII serialization of origin.
6. If serialized is "null", set it to an **implementation-defined value**.

   ...

What is this **implementation-defined value**?

UPDATE: I try to implement this on `jsdom`, so want to figure out what should I do.

Comment: Well it's up to implementations to define it ;-) (Chrome, FF, and Safari seems to set it to `'null'`. Not sure for IE.)

Comment: I try to implement this on jsdom, so want to figure out what should I do. :)

Comment: Well this case can be reproduced in an crossorigin sandboxed iframe. And for once it is useful, SO's stacksnippets are crossorigin  sandboxed and if you type in there `console.log(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([])));` you'll get `blob:null/`+ UUID in most browsers. I guess it's safe to say that you can just set it to `'null'` then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an implementer, **It's up to you**, as long as it's not a valid origin.

Most browsers (tested in FF, chrome and Safari) seems to set it to `'null'`.

We can check it thanks to the sand-boxed iframe of stacksnippet.

```js
console.log(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([])));
```

Comment: Thank for the answer.

Comment: @unional, you're welcome. Note that Edge sets it to `''` (empty string), but they do it for every origin...